# Solidity on Remix IDE- Parser Error - Expected Identifier but got 'Number'

Tags: javascript, web3js, remix

> ParserError on uint 256- Expected Identifier but got 'Number'

```
contract SimpleStorage {
    //this will get initialized to 0
    uint256 favoriteNumber;

    struct People {
        uint 256 favoriteNumber;
        string name;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your code - an extra space at the `favoriteNumber` definition.

Replace `uint 256` to `uint256`